# window.open is not working in IE 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, bookmarklet, window.open

I have a little bookmarklet that opens up a new window, only problem is, it's not working. I have tried the "no spaces in title trick" as well as a few others, (took out the void() part, put quotes around all the width, height, and so on) but it still won't fly. Here is the code below:

```
javascript:void(window.open('https://myfavs.me/create.php?f_url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&f_title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),'Add_Page_to_MyFavs.me','width=400,height=300,menubar=no,status=yes,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes'))
```

The error that I am getting is:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 1 Feb 2011 04:59:43 UTC
>   Message: Invalid argument.
>   Line: 1
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: https://myfavs.me/

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internet Explorer is notoriously picky when it comes to names of windows. I suspect that changing `Add_Page_to_MyFavs.me` to `AddPageToMyFavs` will clear up the problem.

Comment: That worked wonders! Thanks so much! From now on all my names for windows will only be alphanumeric.